# Rolling mean of 1 year after filtering of data in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to calculate the rolling mean for 1 year in the below pandas dataframe. 'mean_1year' for the below dataframe is calcualted using the 1 year calculation based
on month and year.

For example, month and year of first row in the below dataframe is '05' and '2016'. Hence 'mean_1year' is calculated using average 'price' of '2016-04' back to '2015-04'.Hence it
would be (1300+1400+1500)/3 = 1400. Also, while calculating this average, a filter has to be made on the "type" column. As the "type" of first row is "A", while calculating "mean_1year",
the rows have to be filtered on type=="A" and the average is computed using '2016-04' back to '2015-04'.

```
type year   month    price  mean_1year
A    2016   05       1200   1400
A    2016   04       1300
A    2016   01       1400
A    2015   12       1500
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Ordinary" *rolling* can't be applied, because it:

- includes rows starting from the current row, whereas you want
  to **exclude** it,
- the range of the window expands into the **future**,
  whereas you want to expand it **back**.

So I used different approach, based on *loc* with suitable
date slices.

As a test DataFrame I used:

```
  type  year  month  price
0    A  2016      5   1200
1    A  2016      4   1300
2    A  2016      1   1400
3    A  2015     12   1500
4    B  2016      5   1200
5    B  2016      4   1300
```

And the code is as follows:

1. Compute date offsets of 12 months and 1 day:

   ```
   yearOffs = pd.offsets.DateOffset(months=12)
   dayOffs = pd.offsets.DateOffset(days=1)
   ```

   Will be needed in *loc* later.
2. Set the index to a *datetime*, derived from *year* and
   *month* columns:

   ```
   df.set_index(pd.to_datetime(df.year.astype(str)
       + df.month.astype(str), format='%Y%m'), inplace=True)
   ```
3. Define the function to compute means within the current
   group:

   ```
   def myMeans(grp):
       wrk = grp.sort_index()
       return wrk.apply(lambda row: wrk.loc[row.name - yearOffs
           : row.name - dayOffs, 'price'].mean(), axis=1)
   ```
4. Compute the means:

   ```
   means = df.groupby('type').apply(myMeans).swaplevel()
   ```

   So far the result is:

   ```
               type
   2015-12-01  A          NaN
   2016-01-01  A       1500.0
   2016-04-01  A       1450.0
   2016-05-01  A       1400.0
   2016-04-01  B          NaN
   2016-05-01  B       1300.0
   dtype: float64
   ```

   but *df* has a **single** level index, with non-unique values.
5. So to add *means* to *df* and drop now unnecessary index,
   the last step is:

   ```
   df = df.set_index('type', append=True).assign(mean_1year=means)\
       .reset_index(level=1).reset_index(drop=True)
   ```

The final result is:

```
  type  year  month  price  mean_1year
0    A  2016      5   1200      1400.0
1    A  2016      4   1300      1450.0
2    A  2016      1   1400      1500.0
3    A  2015     12   1500         NaN
4    B  2016      5   1200      1300.0
5    B  2016      4   1300         NaN
```

For the "earliest" rows in each group the result is *NaN*,
as there are no source (earlier) rows to compute the means
for them (so there is apparently something wrong in the other solution).

Answer (score 2):

First you need a datetime index in ascending order so you can apply a rolling time period calculation.

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['year'].astype('str')+'-'+df['month'].astype('str'))
df = df.set_index('date')
df = df.sort_index()
```

Then you groupby type and apply the rolling mean.

```
df['mean_1year'] = df.groupby('type')['price'].rolling('365D').mean().reset_index(0,drop=True)
```

The result is:

```
           type  year  month  price  mean_1year
date                                           
2015-12-01    A  2015     12   1500      1500.0
2016-01-01    A  2016      1   1400      1450.0
2016-04-01    A  2016      4   1300      1400.0
2016-05-01    A  2016      5   1200      1350.0
```